# List Comprehension starting at a specific number

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I was trying to create this `[80000, 104000, 135000...]` list in Python. Its the value, starting at 80,000 multiplied by 1.3 each time I want

What i've tried:

```
a = [num*1.5 for num in ??? if num>=80000] #???--> i've tried range(10)
```

I should be able to do this but I can't find any solutions rn..
I must use list-comprehensions, if possible.

Some help would be nice, thank you!

Comment: You want an infinite sequence of these numbers?

Comment: What are the rules for building list?

Comment: *"i've tried range(10)"* well, how would anything in `range(10)` be `>=80000` ?

Comment: list comprehensions must have an end. If you want an infinite generator you'd need to use one of the tools available in the `itertools` module.

Comment: @rdas I want the 100 first numbers...

Comment: To be clear, the reason it didn't do anything is that `range(10)` produces `9` as its highest output, but you only include numbers `if num>=80000`.

Comment: Obviously `range` didn't work as you expected. Have you tried reading the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range)? The **very** first example shows exactly what `range(10)` is doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a very basic mathematical operation that represents multiplying by the same value many time: *power*.

```
a = [80000 * (1.3**n) for n in range(100)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own generator then use that in conjunction with a list comprehension.

```
def numgen(start, factor, limit):
    for _ in range(limit):
        yield int(start)
        start *= factor

mylist = [value for value in numgen(80_000, 1.3, 10)]

print(mylist)
```

**Output:**

```
[80000, 104000, 135200, 175760, 228488, 297034, 386144, 501988, 652584, 848359]
```

Answer (score -3):

```py
import numpy as np
print(80000 * 1.3**np.arange(3))
# [ 80000. 104000. 135200.]
```

Comment: Does everything need to depend on numpy…?

Comment: @deceze Python without numpy is possible, but pointless.

Comment: That very much depends on what you *do* with Python. I've been happily coding in Python for many years without touching numpy.

Comment: Why exactly is it "pointless"? What do you think is the benefit of numpy here, other making the code need additional module to be installed?

Comment: @Hyperplane  "Python without numpy is possible, but pointless. " what :D ?

Comment: @matszwecja installed *and* compiled... some people don't care a bit for overhead, unfortunately

Comment: @DeepSpace *"if all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail"*

Comment: Python was first released on 20 February 1991 while numpy on 14 March 2006. Good to know that Python was pointless for 15 years

Comment: @DeepSpace It's supposed to be a reference to the common idiom *"Life without X is possible, but pointless."* Obviously, you can live without X, it's just worse. For me, not using the incredible convenience that numpy brings falls under that category. I guess it was my mistake for trying to contribute something here.

Comment: BTW, I was obliquely referencing this common SO meme: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/476. Recently numpy seems to have become to Python questions as jQuery used to be for Javascript.

Comment: @Hyperplane I gotta admit, the downvotes are a bit of unjustified. `numpy` IS a useful tool, but it's not universal. There is no reason to bloat Python with modules when we've got just as good solution built into the language. Python without numpy is in no way worse for the huge amount of people that do not need its functionalities and NumPy based solution can actually MAKE things worse when trying to combine them with something that was not built with NumPy in mind.